# Trying to pass an object to a spring controller using Jquery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass a javascript object

```
var questionConstraintLineItem = {
       "string1": "bhanu",
       "string2": "prasad"
};
```

Using jQuery getJson

```
$.getJSON("/SafeSiteLive/common/createTaskWizard/saveTask.json", {
            questionConstraintLineItem: questionConstraintLineItem
        }, function (data)
        {
            try {
                dialog.dialog("close");
                getGroups();
            } catch (e) {
                alert("An exception occurred in the script. Error name: " + e.name + ". Error message: " + e.message);
            }
});
```

To my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "common/createTaskWizard/saveTask.json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void saveTask(
        QuestionConstraintLineItem questionConstraintLineItem) { 
  rest of the code...
```

I have tried using @RequestParam("questionConstraintLineItem") also.

Neither method works. Without the @RequestParam the request goes through to the server but the object is not filled with the data.

Am I doing this the wrong way?

Here is the QuestionConstaintLineItem POJO

```
public class QuestionConstraintLineItem implements Serializable{
private String string1;
private String string2;

public String getString1() {
    return string1;
}

public void setString1(String string1) {
    this.string1 = string1;
}

public String getString2() {
    return string2;
}

public void setString2(String string2) {
    this.string2 = string2;
}


}
```

Here is the error I get when I use the @RequestParam.

[image]

Comment: How does `QuestionConstraintLineItem` POJO look like? What are the error messages in each case? What does your browser's network tab report?

Comment: Added the POJO, no error message in the first case, the questionConstraintLineItem in the controller just doesn't have any values (both string1 and string 2 are null). I'll post the error to the second case.

Comment: You should annotate it with `@RequestBody` because you are sending JSON. Also not sure if that would work with a GET request (nor should you be sending it with a GET but a POST imho). If you want to use request parameters you have to encode them into the URL else no binding will happen.

Comment: I have also tried @RequestBody and it doesn't work. How do I go about doing a post?